# Preposition at the end of infinitives vs. no preposition

Tags: prepositions, infinitives

> You need a pen to write.
>
> You need a pen to write with.

Are there any differences between the two sentences above? Which is more commonly spoken?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"You need a pen to write"* means *"You need a pen **in order to** write".* In other words, you can't write without a pen.

*"You need a pen to write with"* is grammatically correct too but the meaning is different. Now the point is, you are emphasizing the instrument: *"You need **a pen which you can use** to write."*

The use of the sentences depends on context, of course.

Answer (score 0):

There are actually *two* meanings of the first sentence:

> 1) You need a pen **in order** to write.
>   2) You need a pen **that is able** to write.

The second meaning is less common, but still used:

> "I can't get this pen to write!" she said while shaking it.

Your second sentence doesn't have the exact meaning of either of these.